# Eureka - DateRow load date without changing its current value

Tags: swift, callback, eureka-forms

This is my eureka daterow code. Where row value is set only after making any changes in the datepickerview. I need to load the date to row on cell selection on the daterow. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
form +++ DateRow(name)  {
        $0.title = label
}.onChange({ (row) in
    if let value = row.value {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let date = dateFormatter.string(from: value)

        let item = CustomField(coulmnId: fieldId, columnValue: date)
        self.addToCustom(set: item)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the `row` `value` so that `picker` can use that at startup,

```
form +++ DateRow("name")  {
            $0.title = "label"
        }.onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
            if row.value == nil {
                row.value = Date()// Set default value.
            }
        }).onChange({ (row) in
        ...
```

Comment: Since it is a non mandatory field, i cannot cll it on initialisation. How can i set value on event `onCellSelection()`

Comment: @VaisakhKp Updated the answer.

Comment: Does the DateRow have any events like `onPresent()` ?

Comment: No, there is no `onPresent` callback. What do you want to achieve btw? You can check all callbacks [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/master/Source/Core/RowType.swift)